# How to use UITextAlignment to align text in UITableViewCell to the right and left in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I have to align text in table cell to right and left.I have used two plist in my application 
according to plist selection I have to align my text in table cell.

I try following code for that

```
if ([app.currentPlist isEqualToString:@"Accounting.plist"]) {
    cell.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;            
} else {
    cell.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewCell` doesn't have a `textAlignment` property. You have to set it on the cell's text label:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Something";

    if([app.currentPlist isEqualToString:@"Accounting.plist"])
    {
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;             
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;           
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Vishal P - I used your code! - however you put in the cellForRowAtIndexPath... see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

`UITextAlignmentRight` is deprecated, use `NSTextAlignmentLeft` instead

So, the code will be - 
`cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;`

Answer (score 1):

In swift it is

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
```